# How to create a SalesForce 'User' with REST API?

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to create a User in SFDC  with REST API on Java Client.
Please see my code below and help me to understand why I am getting the error message below:

```
HTTP Status 400 ::
{
errorCode: "NOT_FOUND"
message: "The requested resource does not exist"
}
```

CODE:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
JSONObject user = new JSONObject();
String userId = null;

try{

    user.put("Username", "email@domain.com");
    user.put("Alias", "DemoAPI");
    user.put("ProfileId", "00e90000000fKXB");
    user.put("Email", "email123456@domain.com");
    user.put("EmailEncodingKey", "ISO-8859-1");
    user.put("LastName", "REST API Test");
    user.put("LanguageLocaleKey", "pt_BR");
    user.put("LocaleSidKey", "pt_BR");
    user.put("TimeZoneSidKey", "America/Sao_Paulo");

    PostMethod post = new PostMethod( instanceURL + "/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/User");
    post.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth " + accessToken);
    post.setRequestEntity(new StringRequestEntity(user.toString(), "application/json", null));

    httpClient.executeMethod(post);

}catch(Exception e){}
```

Comment: Perhaps your account doesn't have access rights to the User object?

Answer (score 4):

I used the Chrome Postman plugin to POST the following:

[image: POST request to Salesforce REST API]

Note that the resource URL was set to: (I'm assuming you are on AP1 based the the [pod identifier](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/7665/102) in the ProfileId).

```
https://na5.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/User
```

I got the response:

```
[
    {
        "message": "Duplicate Username.<br>The username already exists in this or another Salesforce organization. Usernames must be unique across all Salesforce organizations. To resolve, use a different username (it doesn't need to match the user's email address). ",
        "errorCode": "DUPLICATE_USERNAME",
        "fields": [
            "Username"
        ]
    }
]
```

Which is fine for testing purposes. It would have probably worked with a different username and free licenses.

Please confirm that your PostMethod URL is set to:

```
https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v29.0/sobjects/User
```

In particular, check that there is no trailing slash on `instanceURL`.